# GetFeatureInfo template of MapServer not replacing values

Tags: mapserver, getfeatureinfo, mapfile, template

I am using MapServer 7.4.2 and I am trying to setup a WMS GetFeatureInfo using  `OUTPUTFORMAT` instead of direct `TEMPLATE` but variables are not replaced

On MapServer file layer definition using:

```
TEMPLATE 'html.tmpl'
```

and with a `html.tmpl`:

```
<!-- MapServer Template -->
:
<b>Value: </b>[value_0]<br>
:
```

I have the proper value reply on QGIS 2.18

```
Value:125
```

When I try to implement  it by replacing the template location with

```
TEMPLATE 'getfeatureinfo_html'
```

and creating an `OUTPUTFORMAT` option as follows

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
 NAME "getfeatureinfo_html"
 DRIVER "TEMPLATE"
 FORMATOPTION "FILE=html.tmpl"
 MIMETYPE "text/html"
END
```

The server replies with the correct template BUT the variable is not replaced, resulting in an output like:

```
<b>Value: </b>[value_0]<br>
```

Therefore the variable is not being replace and on logs (level 5) I have no indication or an error.

It looks like MapServer is not aware the layer from where to pull the value. Looked at documentation and examples but is not clear how to achieve it (missing layer information).

Later I would like to have a GetFeatureInfo for WMS with multiple mimetype options

Any tips or solutions?

Comment: By the documentation you should have there `[item name=value_0]` https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html.

Comment: Thank you, but even using the proposed `[item name=value_0]` the variables are not replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the mapserver mailing there was several suggestion but this worked for mapserver 7.6.0

The template file for JSON named `wrb.js` (
[see here mapserver geojson template](https://mapserver.org/output/template_output.html#geojson) ) has a result set for each layer,

```
// mapserver template
[resultset layer="Acrisols"]{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    [feature trimlast=","]
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "[qlayer]",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [[x], [y]]
          }
        ]
      }
[/feature]
  ]}
[/resultset]
[resultset layer="Albeluvisols"]{
:
:
[/resultset]
```

Then the mapfile:

```
MAP
:
    OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "geojson"
        DRIVER "TEMPLATE"
        MIMETYPE "application/geo+json"
        FORMATOPTION "FILE=wrb.js"
    END
    
    OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "html"
        DRIVER "TEMPLATE"
        MIMETYPE "text/html"
        FORMATOPTION "FILE=wrb.html"
    END
:


  WEB
:
       'wms_feature_info_mime_type' 'text/html,application/geo+json'
:

 LAYER
      NAME "Acrisols"
:
      TYPE RASTER
      TEMPLATE 'DUMMY'
      STATUS  ON
```

Tried to use `[include file=common.js]` for eache layer but it didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like MapServer is not aware the layer from where to pull the value

You need to reference the template in the layer like:

```
LAYER
     NAME "GBR_BGS_625k_BLT" #Bedrock lithology
     TYPE POLYGON
     STATUS ON
     DATA "bedrock625ll"
     TRANSPARENCY 100
     TOLERANCE 0
     TOLERANCEUNITS pixels
     TRANSFORM TRUE
     PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
     HEADER "tmpl/bedrock_lithology_query_header.html"
     TEMPLATE "tmpl/bedrock_lithology_query_body.html"
     FOOTER "tmpl/bedrock_lithology_query_footer.html"
     PROJECTION
         ...
```